# Laravel File Manager - Can't access my media manager (HTTP error 500)

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, file-manager

I am using the [**Backpack**](https://backpackforlaravel.com/) framework and When I open my Media Manager (File Manager) I get the error below showing.

[image]

My site is hosted on OVH.

I tried everything, change the permissions of my files, I modified the **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** variables in my .user.ini, but nothing changes.

I also specify that I changed the hosting of the site which was before on Plesk (I did not have this error before).

Comment: And what is the error ? Open that network 500 and see the response and share it

Comment: I just have a message "Server Error".

Comment: What about if you check the laravel logs on the server ?

Comment: I doesn't have laravel logs on my server.

Comment: How is that ? If it is erroring out a 500, you must have a log somewhere

Comment: To get a better picture of what's wrong, you can set your `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.ENV` file. Then it's possible the error will be more specific, if you click the red item in your Chrome DevTools. What does it say then?

Comment: Thank you all. I solved my problem, it was a php version problem, on my old hosting the php version was at 7.2 and on my new hosting at 7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change accommodation? I had the same problem before, it could just be a bad version of PHP. Try to change your version of PHP.